# Testing input in MochaJS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm fairly new to the MochaJS testing framework and I'm trying to validate a dropdown menu in response to user input. I have a component with the following method:

inside my **Search component**:

```
  createQueryInputEl() {
    const inputEl = document.createElement('input');
    Object.assign(inputEl, {
      type: 'search',
      name: 'query',
      autocomplete: 'off',
    });

    inputEl.addEventListener('input', event =>
      this.onQueryChange(this, event.target.value));
```

The `onQueryChange()` function creates a dropdown by creating an `li` element for each result like this:

```
createResultsEl(results) {
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    results.forEach((result) => {
      const el = document.createElement('li');
      Object.assign(el, {
        className: 'result',
        textContent: result.text,
      });

      // Pass the value to the onSelect callback
      el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        const { onSelect } = this.options;
        if (typeof onSelect === 'function') onSelect(result.text);
        this.displaySelected(this.inputEl, result.text)
      });

      fragment.appendChild(el);
    });
    return fragment;
  }
```

In MochaJS, I'm trying to test the population of that dropdown like this:

```
    it('should populate input on value selection', () => {

          const input = document.querySelector('input');
          input.value = "New"
          input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

          const results = document.querySelectorAll('.result');
      
          expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    })
```

The problem is that `results` keeps coming up empty. When I enter that code into the console, `results` is a `NodeList` with each `li` element of the result.

How do I get MochaJS to simulate this behavior?